# If I remove a node's children without removing *their* children first, what happens to these grandchildren?

Tags: javascript, html, nodes, children

I have a container node to which I've appended a number of labels, each of which has its own children:

```
var container = document.getElementById("my_container");
var my_label, some_element, other_element;
for (let i=0;i<some_number;i++) {
    container.appendChild(my_label);
    my_label.appendChild(some_element);
    my_label.appendChild(other_element);
}
```

At some point, I remove all instances of my_label from container, so I could add other elements to container:

```
while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
     container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
}
```

Note that in doing so, I do not remove any instances of some_element and other_element. What happens to these children of my_label? Is my code clean, or should I first remove all children of my_label and then remove my_label?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: What is the issue with code at Question?

Comment: As long as nothing holds a reference to them (eg stored in some variable)  they will get garbage collected sooner or later. Note if you keep `my_label` set to the same element it will still hold a reference to the that element and its children so neither will be garbage collected till the variable is cleared / garbage collected

Comment: guest271314: I wasn't sure whether there was in fact an issue with my code--that's why I asked the question. I'm new at Javascript.

Comment: Patrick Evans: thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens to these children of my_label?

Nothing. They're not referenced by any script variables or the DOM any more, so they will get garbage-collected together with the label.

> Is my code clean?

Yes.

> Should I first remove all children of my_label and then remove my_label?

No, you don't need to recursively walk the whole DOM subtree and pull everything apart.